# IIS cannot load global type despite of existing dll

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-6

I'm trying to get an application to run on an IIS 6.0 that I was assigned to support.

I copied all the source and binaries to the Inetput folder. The WebApp is running, but I get the error that tells me that the global type of the application could not be loaded.

How can I debug this? The namespace is correct, the DLL is present in the /bin/ folder of the application, and still the app cannot load it.

After turning on Fusion logging, I found this error file that concerns my global class;

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (05.11.2012 @ 08:45:30) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80131107. No description available.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\fusion.dll
Running under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = MyApplication
 (Partial)
LOG: Appbase = file:///c:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyApplication
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\Temporary ASP.NET Files\MyApplication\a1144233
LOG: Cache Base = C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\Temporary ASP.NET Files\MyApplication\a1144233
LOG: AppName = 1ec25e47
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===

LOG: Processing DEVPATH.
LOG: DEVPATH is not set. Falling through to regular bind.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Post-policy reference: MyApplication
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v1.1.4322/Temporary ASP.NET Files/MyApplication/a1144233/1ec25e47/MyApplication.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v1.1.4322/Temporary ASP.NET Files/MyApplication/a1144233/1ec25e47/MyApplication/MyApplication.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyApplication/bin/MyApplication.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApplication\bin\MyApplication.DLL
LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
ERR: Error extracting manifest import from file (hr = 0x80131107).
ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x80131107.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131107). Probing terminated.
```

What's going wrong there? The `bin\MyApplication.DLL` exists and is compiled correctly, so I don't see the problem...

Comment: Are there any 32/64 bit issues.  Have you turned on [fusion logging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thottams/archive/2007/06/02/debugging-load-problems-using-fusion-log.aspx)?

Comment: It's all compiled and run on a 32bit machine, and on 32bit targets...

Comment: Did you check the fusion logging option?

Comment: I turned on fusion logging and got the error message... but that's not really helping me

Comment: What version of .Net Framwork does the dll run under? because IIS is configured to use version 1.1?

Comment: I just checked, and it seems the DLL runs under 2.0... Visual Studio 2010 doesn't support 1.1 anymore, so yeah... recompile in Studio 2003 and everything's fine. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproducing the solution from the comments...

Step 1 is to enable [Fusion Logging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thottams/archive/2007/06/02/debugging-load-problems-using-fusion-log.aspx) to get a log of what was failing

This produced the log file that indicates that IIS was trying to launch the DLL under version 1.1 of the .Net Framework.   The error then occurred when it tried to read the manifest of the dll.

This indicates that the dll was from a later version of the framework and so couldn't be loaded.